# HTTP 502 from one instance of an Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-diagnostics, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We suddenly began experiencing HTTP 502 errors (`The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process`) from **one** of the instances of our web app. I was able to determine this using Kudu's "Support" tab whereby you can drill down to metrics per instance.

After restarting w3wp for the instance everything continued successfully as normal. There were no problems with resource usage (CPU/RAM) and **the odd thing is that the 502s were returning instantly.** So, requests weren't timing out for the client.

**What are the possible steps to investigate why this happened?**

Our application logs wouldn't have anything and our web server logs only have the record of these 502 but with no further details.

Comment: did you open a support ticket?

Comment: @astaykov: Yes, we have created one.

Comment: Have you solved this one? if so, can you elaborate on how you overcame from that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our case it seems to have come down to port exhaustion on the app service plan. [Read here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#cross-vm-numerical-limits) for more details on the limitations for each of the plans available.